# Swift: Shorthand way of moving JSON strings to an array

Tags: ios, json, swift

I have a project where I have to take a bunch of Logo URL's and Title's from a JSON object and then I have used Alamofire and SwiftyJSON to extract this information like so:

```
    Alamofire.request(.POST, postJsonURL, parameters: postParameters, encoding: .JSON).responseJSON {
        (request, response, json, error) -> Void in
        if (json != nil) {
            var jsonObj = JSON(json!)
            var title1 = jsonObj[0]["title"].stringValue
            var title2 = jsonObj[1]["title"].stringValue
            var title3 = jsonObj[2]["title"].stringValue
            var title4 = jsonObj[3]["title"].stringValue
            var title5 = jsonObj[4]["title"].stringValue
            var image1 = jsonObj[0]["logoURL"].stringValue
            var image2 = jsonObj[1]["logoURL"].stringValue
            var image3 = jsonObj[2]["logoURL"].stringValue
            var image4 = jsonObj[3]["logoURL"].stringValue
            var image5 = jsonObj[4]["logoURL"].stringValue
            self.images = [image1, image2, image3, image4, image5]
            self.titles = [title1, title2, title3, title4, title5]
        }
    }
```

This works at the minute but it is driving me mad because it's a big disregard to the DRY principle and it would take forever to change it by tedious typing, should I need to. I was just wondering what's a good way to refactor this as I have ran out of ideas. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use a loop:

```
   Alamofire.request(.POST, postJsonURL, parameters: postParameters, encoding: .JSON).responseJSON {
        (request, response, json, error) -> Void in
        if (json != nil) {
            var jsonObj = JSON(json!)
            self.images = []
            self.titles = []

            for (var i=0; i < 5; ++i) {
                self.images.append(jsonObj[i]["logoURL"].stringValue)
                self.titles.append(jsonObj[i]["title"].stringValue)
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to collect *all*(not `0...4`) elements, just iterate `jsonObj`:

```
var jsonObj = JSON(json!)
var images:[String]
var titles:[String]
for (idx, obj) in jsonObj {
    titles.append(obj["title"].stringValue)
    images.append(obj["logoURL"].stringValue)
}
self.images = images
self.titles = titles
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use reduce for tasks like this:

```
var titles = jsonObj.reduce([] as [String]) {
    p, n in
    var temp = p
    temp.append(n["title"]!)
    return temp
}
```